# Chrome extension handle multiple port connections from event page to script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have dug all over the documentations and SO but I couldn't really find examples or descriptions how to open long-lived connections with `chrome.tabs.connect`.  What I want to do is every time a tab gets created, I open a long-lived connection with that tab.  I want keep track which tab the information is coming from.  Here's what I have:

background.js

```
/*CREATING AND STORING A PORT FOR INDIVIDUAL TABS*/
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {
/*SETTIMEOUT BECAUSE CONNECTING RIGHT AWAY DOESN'T REGISTER*/
setTimeout(function() { 
    var port = chrome.tabs.connect(tab.id, {name: tab.id.toString()});
    /*SAVE EACH PORT IN AN ARRAY*/
    portsMod.addPort(port);
    /*TESTING RECEIVING MESSAGES FROM CONTENT SCRIPT ON EACH INDIVIDUAL PAGE*/
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        console.log("CAME FROM " + msg.portNum + " " + msg.timesSent + " TIMES.");
    });
}, 1000);
});
```

script.js

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        /*SEND MESSAGE FROM EACH TAB IN 5sec INTERVALS*/
        port.postMessage({portNum: port.name, timesSent: i});
        i++;
    }, 5000);
}
```

I reload the extension and open a bunch of tabs.  It works but with a lag.  I got it working with up to 15 tabs but it's laggy (for example, I will get one log entry, then 7 more, then the rest at once).  Is this really a proper way of doing it or is there a better way?

Comment: why don't you use content scripts to connect from the content to the background? ive done it like that and not the other way arround like you describe.

Comment: @ZigMandel The reason why I wanted to do it the other way around is because right away when a tab is created, I can specify a port name as the tab id.  Establishing a connection from the script requires a message to be sent to the event page, then a reply to the script with the tab id.